# Data Bind failing for Custom HtmlControl inside ItemTemplate of ListView

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have an ItemTemplate which is set on a ListView:

```
<div class="commentTileTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="commentTileControl" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.HtmlControl" data-win-options="{uri: '/htmlControls/commentTile/commentTile.html'}"></div>
</div>
```

The data bindings which are inside the HtmlControl, fails to bind the first time the ListView is shown, on successive runs, it works fine.

If I remove the template from the ListView, then the raw data shows up as expected, only upon adding the HtmlControl it fails the first.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the first time you are loading the control, the page is loaded asynchronously through an XHR (`WinJS.xhr`) from the package. This means that when the first `WinJS.Binding.process()` happens in the `WinJS.Binding.Template.render` function, the actual content isn't loaded. (e.g. it's query selector doesn't see any `data-win-bind` attributes.

The second time, because the fragment you are loading is already in the fragment cache, it actually renders into the DOM *synchronously* and the `WinJS.Binding.Template.render`'s `WinJS.Binding.processAll` sees those `data-win-bind` attributes.

This leaves you with some options:

1. preload the fragment with `WinJS.UI.Fragments.cache()` as soon as your app starts, and don't set the data on the list view until that fragment completes
2. Only instantiate the `HtmlControl` when your item has been rendered, and then programmatically instantiate the `HtmlControl`, and `WinJS.Binding.process[All]()` the loaded template when it loads [1]
3. Actually make the template your content, and then load the fragment, process the control. This is easier than it looks, but may take some time to think about. In short: Load Fragment, querySelector on the fragment for the element that you have `data-win-control` on, `WinJS.UI.process()` it, and return the template instance back to the caller and use that as the itemTemplate on your list view

[1] The HtmlControl Constructor takes a 3rd parameter, which is a callback called when the fragment is loaded.

Comment: Explicitly calling the render() function of the template after the dataSource has been bound, seems to work fine.

`element.querySelector(".commentsListView").winControl.itemDataSource = commentsBindingList.dataSource;
                    element.querySelector(".commentTileTemplate").winControl.render();`

Is this acceptable or is it because of some GOTCHA that this is working and ideally I should be following one of the options mentioned above?

Comment: Well, you dont know how long the template will take to load -- it's not deterministic, so thats the gotcha.

Are you calling it on the correct container element, or you're just calling it on the actual instance with no parameters?

Comment: I am just calling it on the actual instance with no parameters --
`element.querySelector(".commentTileTemplate").winControl.render();`

where .commentTileTemplate is the <div> given above in the original post.

Comment: I see how this is working -- this is effectively performing option 1. It's an implementation detail -- I would definitely recommend performing option 1 explicitly, rather than this kinda-hacky way. Just one call to WinJS.UI.Fragments.cache("/htmlControls/comments/foo.html") would work great for you. You can even chain it to a promise to set the data source when it's cached.