# How to implement sliding page transition in Metro style app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to implement page transition w/ a slide style in [Metro Style App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/).

The effect looks like

```
    state 1                     state 2                   state 3
 ____________              _______________             ____________  
|            |            |       |       |           |            |
|   page A   |    ====>   |page A |page B |   ====>   |   page B   |
|            |            |partial|partial|           |            |
|____________|            |_______|_______|           |____________|
```

It will be triggered by panning gesture swiping from right to left (w/o triggering system toolbar, well I've no idea how to isolate them).

I've played w/ [exitPage/enterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229780.aspx) but no luck: seems the page A is disappeared before page B gets in.
Also I've read [single page navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx), [code sample of fragment loading](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Fragments-91f66b07#content) and [code sample of scrolling/panning](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scrolling-panning-and-47d70d4c) and think about that putting the current page and the new page in div wrapper and sliding them in the div w/o invoking `navigate()`. But that might break CSS position, and I don't know when could the JS of the new page be invoked safely...

*update 1* perhaps [FlipView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br211711.aspx) could do this?

*update 2* in finding the way to load local pages to `FlipView`, found grasp of helpful links and but still confused...

- [FlipView w/ using `innerHTML` inside `Template` for external RSS feed](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2012/04/08/windows-8-javascript-flipview-control.aspx)
- [bind iframe w/ `ListView`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/winappswithhtml5/thread/4948f9be-c87a-4650-8023-c2a26a2382a2)
- [ListView w/ HTMLControl content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239619/data-bind-failing-for-custom-htmlcontrol-inside-itemtemplate-of-listview)

*update 3* worked out a primitive version of `FlipView` usage by defining `PageControl` of pages altogether and rendering one of the `PageControl` inside FlipView.itemTemplate, does that appropriate?

So, any suitable solution or bright idea for that? Thanks!

Comment: @Adriano Thanks. Seems `enterPage` effects after the `exitPage` of the elder page, and the transition messed up in simulator w/ a large offset or DOM element covering big area. `WinJS.UI.Animation.transitionPage()` mentioned in the link sounds good but there is no such function in WinJS now...

Comment: Are you attempting a cross fade, or merely moving the items off and on in unison, almost like a slide to the left? (or right for RTL).

if you are exitPage.then(function() { enterPage() }), then you will see the content disappear before the new page enters. Did you try running them concurrently?

Can you clarify "messed up" when you say it behaves in correct in the simulator?

Comment: @DominicHopton I've not tried the cross fade, we need the right-to-left and left-to-right flip...can the cross fade achieve that? Not the in unison moving, I've no idea how to concurrently run `exitPage` and `enterPage` for different pages and move them. The "messed up" is that for a large `'left'` value such as `'1000px'` the leaving-page gets stuck for a while and suddenly disappears and leaves there a white screen before the incoming page gets in, maybe this is caused by my slow simulator.

Comment: @DominicHopton ...I've read [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239619/data-bind-failing-for-custom-htmlcontrol-inside-itemtemplate-of-listview) and think about fill `FlipView` w/ rendered `PageControl`(instead of `HTMLControl` because I need in page JS). Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: The FlipView will work. *However* I would definitely suggest taking a look at mandatory snap points; this is what the flip view uses to implement the snapping behavior under the the covers.

Comment: @DominicHopton Good to know that. I've worked out a primitive version of `FlipView` usage by defining `PageControl` of pages altogether and rendering one of the `PageControl` inside `FlipView.itemTemplate`. I would see the snap points in future, but currently I'm on a running of prototype/demo, so hopefully `FlipView` could fulfill current needs. Thanks again =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `FlipView` for this. The code inside `WinJS.UI` in `base.js` explains everything about the effect (as mentioned by Dominic Hopton). The `FlipView` is good enough for my current usage (may need customize for extra flipping behavior in future though).

The `FlipView` loads all pages at once at the start, to reduce the overload, I

1. lazy-load simple placeholder `div` instead of `PageControl` at first and then load/unload the `PageControl` in events `onpagecompleted/onpagechangedvisibility` of the `FlipView`. This brings a side effect that `PageControl.ready/unload` is triggered when the page is visible inside (or hidden from) the viewport, very handy.
2. incrementally load extra pages through `itemDataSource` (maybe also dynamically unload?)

Also, extra `FlipView`s could be used inside `PageControl` wrapped by `FlipView`, MSDN does not mention this.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely use FlipView for this, but I'll be honest I don't know how this works on the HTML side. On the Xaml side you would implement your "Pages" as user controls instead of actual pages, then you'd host them in the FlipView. This can get rather resource intensive if you have a lot of "pages" and data associated with those "pages".

On the Xaml side, each true page (inheriting from Page) is displayed in a Frame. The Frame can only display one page at a time. That's why you're seeing the first page disappear before the animation is complete.

If you don't want the user to be able to flick across several virtual pages or if resources get too intensive, you might not want to use FlipView. Instead, you could use two ContentPresenters and have an animation. ContentPresenterA and ContentPresenterB are side-by-side. The animation slides, and at the end it sets ContentPresenterA to the content of ContentPresenterB and snaps back to the beginning of the animation. It should happen so quickly the user wouldn't notice a jump.

I'm going to ask my co-worker and friend Ryan Joy to hop on here and see if he can talk about how to do these things on the HTML side.

Comment: Thanks for the confidence, I'm looking at FlipView =) The resource intensive seems to be an issue because there are dozens of pages, hmm.